# how to play mp4 file using html url IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller, mp4

I have been trying to play a mp4 file, I am receiving url from server, I have given that to MPMoviePlayerController, player is loading but file is not playing. Here is the code...

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:obj->msg_url]; // obj->url is a html php url not a direct file url.
    moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                    initWithContentURL:url];

    moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault; 
    moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

So in this case how can I use MPMoviePlayerController to play from html url. Any idea?

thanks

Comment: can u share the link from which are trying to play mp4 file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded first and played its working now.

```
        NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"sample.mp4"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


        NSURL *file_url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
                        initWithContentURL:file_url];

        moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
        moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = YES;
        [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
        [moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`[moviePlayer play];`
It seems shouldAutoplay does not always have the desired effect.

Comment: You didn't say it was a php url. Is this from YouTube? In that case, try https://github.com/hellozimi/HCYoutubeParser.